# Is there a way to create a Quarkus Test Resource of the application itself?

Tags: java, quarkus, quarkus-testing

I am attempting to create a java application that will communicate with other instances of the application hosted by peers via HTTP requests. As such, I want to be able to generate test cases that simulate different nodes communicating with one another. Is there a way of creating a QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager or similar that will spin up an instance of my Quarkus application (ideally where I can specify the port)? Then I am able to create predictable test scenarios where various peers are engaging with one another.

I have scoured all Quarkus documentation in great detail and have not been able to find what I am looking for.

I have attempted something similar to the below:

```
public class TestResource implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        
        Quarkus.run("-Dquarkus.http.port=8082");

        return Map.of(
                ConfigProperties.QUARKUS_PORT,
                "8082"
        );
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        Quarkus.asyncExit();
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, this has not had the desired result but I hope it highlights what I am attempting to achieve.

Comment: https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource - use wiremock

Comment: Can you explain the use case a little more? Why doesn't the application spun up by `@QuarkusTest` fit your needs?

Comment: @geoand I want multiple instances of the application spun up and talking to each other. Multiple instances such that I can test how the peers interact. As far as I am aware, `@QuarkusTest` does not enable that functionality as it will only create a single instance? Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci thank you for your comment. I will attempt to use a `WireMockServer` and update if successful.

Comment: @LucaBassoRicci your solution does indeed work! Thank you. I would upvote / mark as correct answer but think I need a higher reputation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@QuarkusTest` just spin up a single instance of your application so the only way to have multiple instances of your application is to emulate them using `Wiremock` as describe in [official doc](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource) and stub all you need for you test.